# Tsql transpose rows to columns, grouping by a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've this set of data:

```
cId    item     value
-------------------------------------
1      A        string1
2      A        string2
3      A        string3
1      B        string4
2      B        string5
1      C        string6
3      C        string7
```

And i would to transpose `item` ad `cId` rows into columns, in order to have this result:

```
cId        A           B             C
----------------------------------------------
1          string1     string4       string6  
2          string2     string5       NULL
3          string3     NULL          string7
```

`item` and `cId` rows are not fixed, so i think i need some of dynamic sql for pivoting.
How can i do in tsql?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do it:

```
DECLARE @pivotFields varchar(255) =
    STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ', [' + item + ']'
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT item
                    FROM YourTable
                ) Q
            ORDER BY item
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        )
        , 1, 2, ''
    )

DECLARE @sql varchar(1000) =
    '
        SELECT cId, ' + @pivotFields + '
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    cId
                    , item
                    , value
                FROM YourTable
            ) Q
            PIVOT
            (
                MAX(value)
                FOR item IN (' + @pivotFields + ')
            ) P
    '

EXEC (@sql)
```